# npm.cmd closes instantly after few seconds

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm learning nodeJs. I managed to run nodejs commands on cmd and it works fine. Now I want to install express framework and for that in the tutorial I'm following it asks to type `sudo install -g express` on npm command prompt. So I typed npm in my windows search, and clicked on it. Right after few seconds less  than 3 it closes straight away.

I found that npm.cmd exist in nodejs directory where node.exe found. What could be the problem here. If I were to type the above mentioned command in windows cmd, it says sudo is unrecognized program.SO must I use npm cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `cmd.exe` , I guess you would have node installed but still run `node -v` , it should respond with the version meaning it's working.
Now if you want to explicitly install express.js you just have to run on, the command prompt itself,

`npm install express -g`.

Anyways you can follow this [link](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html) from their official website. Hope it helps. Also `sudo` is a program for Unix like operating systems, just in case you needed it.

Comment: just one more after installing express, I tried using exxpress command to create hello-express file but it says express is not recognized. The command is: express hello-express

Comment: is the exact error that "express is not recognised as a external or internal command" something like this? Did you use the `-g` flag , it installs it globally? Well check the path environment variable. Also do `npm install -g express-generator`. It should work.

Comment: seems like working after I typed out npm install -g express-generator...how do you know this much where did you find out, if you don't mind?

Comment: same way you did right now...after running into errors. Anyway just reading the official documentation should suffice for starting out , its the link shared earlier.

Comment: Thanks @wolfsgang for your help, appreciate it a lot