# Trying to install cordova with 'npm.cmd' but automatically close after a few second

Tags: node.js, git, cordova, npm

I want to learn about developing android apps using Cordova. I'm using [this tutorial](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/#installing-the-cordova-cli).

I can't proceed to the next steps:

```
C:\>npm install -g cordova
```

Because when I open the `npm.cmd` it always automatically closes after 0.5 seconds!

I dont know why.
i have tried from this StackOverflow thread: 
[npm.cmd closes instantly after few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37781952/npm-cmd-closes-instantly-after-few-seconds#)

But still can't open `npm.cmd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `npm.cmd` use your platform terminal on windows you can open `command Prompt` check for node you can use `node -v` if node exists you can run `npm install -g cordova`

Comment: @sebastian glad to hear that